# How to access array variable outside from javascript closure?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to access variable declared inside javascript closure?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CLOSURE_VAR = (function() {

        var privateVar = {
                arr: []
            };
    return {
        setVar: function(name,name2) {
            privateVar['arr'][name] = name2;
        },
        getVar: function(name) {
            return privateVar['arr'][name];
        },
        getPrivateVar: function(name) {
            return privateVar[name];
        }
    };

}());
function initializeArr(name) {
    CLOSURE_VAR.setVar(name,"y");
    CLOSURE_VAR.setVar("def","z");
} 
function checkVar(name) {
    alert(CLOSURE_VAR.getVar(name));
    console.log(CLOSURE_VAR.getPrivateVar('arr')+"--------------------");
    alert(CLOSURE_VAR.getVar("def"));
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeArr('abc')">
    <a href="#" onclick="checkVar('abc')">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

While page loading I am inserting the values into the array. When I click on the link I want to get the array(with data) like [abc: "y", def: "z"] but MODULE.getPrivateVar('arr') returning blank;

Comment: where is `MODULE` defined?

Comment: `privateVar['arr'][iName] = name2;` — what is `iName`?  The parameters are `name` and `name2`.

Comment: `Module` doesn't exist, don't you mean `CLOSURE_VAR`, also you have defined your `CLOSURE_VAR` wrong. Before `initializeArr` you write `}());` it is supposed to be `})();`

Comment: Sorry, type mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `arr` as an Array rather than an Object.

Run this code snippet:

```js
var CLOSURE_VAR = (function() {

  var privateVar = {
    arr: {}
  };
  
  return {
    setVar: function(name, name2) {
      privateVar['arr'][name] = name2;
    },
    getVar: function(name) {
      return privateVar['arr'][name];
    },
    getPrivateVar: function(name) {
      return privateVar[name];
    }
  };

}());

function initializeArr(name) {
  CLOSURE_VAR.setVar(name, "y");
  CLOSURE_VAR.setVar("def", "z");
}

function checkVar(name) {
  console.log(CLOSURE_VAR.getVar(name));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(CLOSURE_VAR.getPrivateVar('arr')) + "--------------------");
  console.log(CLOSURE_VAR.getVar("def"));
}

initializeArr('abc');
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="checkVar('abc')">hello</a>
```

See? now the object is being printed.

- I've changed `arr` from `Array[]` to `Object{}`.
- I've used `stringify` to get a version of that object as String.

Comment: @ManasB Good! :-)

Comment: But, if I use object instead of Array(native) will it cause performance issue?

Comment: @ManasB no, actually you’re going to get benefits because objects are optimized key-value pairs structures.